# TreeListEx, field set using template _StandardValues not being retrieved from sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm having some serious issues with setting an items values be `_StandardValues` in sitecore. I have a sitecore item and I retrieve it's data simply thus:

```
Item rawItem = service.Database.GetItem(new ID(id));
```

I subsequently extended said item's template and added a new `TreeListEx`. I populated this treelist from standard values:

[image]

The problem is the standard values are not getting retrieved by the above code. The field does not exist in the fields collection. What is confusing is if I change the items values, so remove all the standard items and put them back in, it works. The only thing in the UI appears different is that the field goes from:

[image]

to

[image]

i.e. it's not pulling this data from `[standard values]` anymore. **I can now see my fields in `rawItem` (above).**

If I check the `Raw values` of the they are identical (i.e. a collection of Guids as you'd expect):

```
{4E4A364E-16D5-4E09-A4E7-25DB628951FB}|{15E4026A-575A-4787-83B0-A37EB9F0A06D}|{74D1C654-BE53-4FB4-A072-19DA70215F4B}|{C3883CDE-A01E-46B7-B09F-2FB1F4C51C3A}
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a solution, it just came back to life. It appears that I needed to rebuild the link DB. I had tried this previously to no avail, but the difference this time is I rebuilt all 3 (core, web and master) DBs:

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this will help someone with this issue in the future.